# Find the number of equivalence classes of this equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and show that one less divides p-1

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let p be a prime number and gcd(p,n)=1.  Define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as follows: x ~ y iff $n^rx=n^ty$ for some r,t $\geq 0$.  Let m be the number of equivalence classes of this equivalence relation.  Prove that m-1 is a divisor of p-1.

I know that 0 has its own equivalence class so the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ make up the remaining m-1 equivalence classes.

Now all that is left to show is that each of these equivalence classes has the same size.  I read this part on a different question, but I have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the trivial class $\{0\}$,
these equivalence classes are cosets in the group $\Bbb Z_p^\times$
of the nonzero congruence classes of integers modulo $p$. They are the
cosets of the subgroup $H=\left< n\right>$ of the cyclic subgroup
generated by $n$. Each coset has the same size, so $p-1=(m-1)r$
where $r$ is the size of $H$.

Comment: I don't understand why these are cosets of that subgroup?  Could you please explain

Comment: @VinnyChase $n^rx\equiv n^ty\pmod p$ iff $n^{r-t}x\equiv y\pmod p$.